# Spring boot update from 1.4.0 to 1.5.10 entityManagerFactory issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I have updated springboot from 1.4.0 to 1.5.10 and then regenerated the entities using jhipster. When I try to run the code I get this exception -

```
   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [C:\WorkArea\hotfix-new\target\classes\com\info\config\SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventMvcEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventMvcEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in file [C:\WorkArea\hotfix-new\target\classes\com\info\repository\CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#186bf8ab' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#186bf8ab': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

If any one has idea then please suggest.

Comment: Yea.  My idea is to read the error message.  It clearly says that something is missing.

Comment: Have you also updated jhipster before re-generating? because migrating from SB 1.4 to 1.5 has already been managed by jhipster itself. https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: yes I have updated jhipster and then spring

Answer (score 0):

`EntityManagerFactory` is normally registered by `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency. Do you have it in your updated project?

Comment: Do you use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is not provided scoped? Normally this missing bean is registered by `JpaBaseConfiguration` which depends on `spring.jpa` properties.